# If original problem is bounded, it seems to imply that it is not necessary to include all variables in resolution theorem. why?

Tags: convex-optimization, linear-programming

I am working from the Bertsimas and Tsitsiklis textbook, exercise 6.2 in chapter 6 available [here](https://www.u-cursos.cl/ingenieria/2010/1/IN3701/2/material_docente/bajar?id_material=289781).  This problem is using the *resolution* theorem to reformulate problems and get the Dantzig-Wolfe Decomposition.  I am unable to resolve (no pun intended) this bit of theory.  The resolution therorem is repeated here:
[image: resolution theorem]
I know that the solution says it is not necessary to include the rays $w_1$ and $w_2$ because the original problem is bounded.  I understand very clearly that the original problem is bounded - there are non-negativity constraints, and bounds on the variables.

But, how does just because the problem is bounded mean that we do not have to include all of the variables $w_1$ and $w_2$?

Comment: just because a bounded polyhedron, that is a polytope, has no extreme rays and by Corollary 4.4 it can be described by the convex hull of its vertices.

Comment: you are confusing the unboundness of the objective function with the unboundness of the feasible region. Observe  that if the feasible region of an LP problem is a bounded polyhedron, that is a polytope, then the problem is bounded for every objective function you can choose. Conversely if the feasible region is an unbounded polyhedron, then there exists at least an objective function that is unbounded over the the polyhedron.

Comment: Good points, can you formulate an answer for not only my own benefit, but for the benefit of the community as well?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are saying the following:  Since the *original* polyhedron $P$ is nonempty and bounded, then we can use corollary 4.4.  And since Corollary 4.4 allows us to use ONLY the extreme points to construct the feasible region, then we only need to use the extreme points in the construction of Q as well.    Is that what you're trying to say @MarcelloSammarra?

Comment: yes, that is what is stated by the Resolution  Theorem and Corollary 4.4

Comment: If you post a well formed answer, I can accept, @MacelloSammarra.